# Date format issue with DatePicker asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

I have a problem with datepicker format, it sets the date to `MM-dd-yyyy`. First, my model was set to following date format `dd-MM-yyyy`, I've changed it to `MM-dd-yyyy` in my model but nothing happen, the jqueryval script throw an error it wants the `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? dateOut_cash
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

So how can I set it to have everything working well ?

Comment: clean soln and then try

Comment: Do you want the `MM-dd-yyyy` format or do you need a different one? You can always specify the target format in the `datepicker` call: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });` Remember that jQuery uses `yy` for the "full" 4 digit year format.

Comment: exactly what I want thank you for your answer!

Comment: What does any of this have to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin?  Please be more mindful when selecting your tags.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry not to be as intelligent as you..

Comment: You don't say in your mind maybe it is not an expert in that field ? Never forget that something could be evident for you but another thing could be very difficult for you. So never denigrate...

Comment: All this is because you are a guru of jquery-valaidate wawwww incredible fantastic..